# libGDX --- image in table drawing white color or font image instead my assets files

Tags: java, image, libgdx

I have a table and images in this table, but the problem is that the image of drawing a white rectangle or font image (although pictures of the font is not present in the assets folder) instead of the texture. Textures from assets folder are images of cards. this may be due to the size of the textures (about 340x500 and 350kb each).

Please help me to solve this problem. I really want to write my first game.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

final Game game;
private Stage stage;
private Table table;
private Image card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6;

private Cards cards;

public GameScreen(Game game, Cards cards) {
    this.game = game;
    this.cards = cards;

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    card1 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("1.png")));
    card2 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("2.png")));
    card3 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("3.png")));
    card4 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("4.png")));
    card5 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("5.png")));
    card6 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("6.png")));

    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.setDebug(true);
    table.add(card1).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).padBottom(10);
    table.add(card2).width(140).height(202).padBottom(10);
    table.add(card3).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).padBottom(10).row();
    table.add(card4).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15);
    table.add(card5).width(140).height(202);
    table.add(card6).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).row();

    stage.addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    mySkin.dispose();
    dixit.getScreen().dispose();
}
```

[image: THIS IS SCREENSHOT]

Comment: You have only add texture to only card2, and for others there is no texture. Can you post a screenshot of your output

Comment: @GodslaveAsad Attached screenshot under my post.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it is seen that only the card2 image you are seeing, which is obvious because you only set/give texture to card2(which is a font image I guess). You need to provide Texture (.png file in your asset folder) for each of the cards

Let you have 1.png, 2.png , 3.png, 4.png files in your asset folder now you have to set them to your Image objects. 
`New Image()` construct a blank texture for you.

here i am setting the pngs to your cards

```
card1 = new Image();
    card2 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("12.png")));
    card3 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("1.png")));
    card4 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("2.png")));
    card5 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("3.png")));
    card6 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("4.png")));
```

So add some card image to your asset folder and set them to the cards.

Comment: I changed my post above. The result is the same(((

Comment: In my game I'm trying to use Google Play Games Services (TurnBasedGame) through the interface. In AndroidLauncher I initiate the initial data and of the AndroidLauncher I call the method `setScreen(new GameScreen())`. Maybe this is wrong??